# How to know if Web activity(ADF V2) ran Analysis Services models process succesfully?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps, azure-analysis-services

I found a tutorial that guided me on how to request an Analysis Services process by using Web Activity requesting an HTTP/REST post method, calling the Logic App service.
https://marczak.io/posts/2019/06/logic-apps-refresh-analysis-services/

However, I need the activity to wait for the end of the processing so we can proceed with the rest of the flow (once it is asynchronous it jumps to the next step).

Can someone help or provide me with any alternative?

I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My preferred approach is to use native Web Activities in ADF rather than adding Logic Apps to the architecture. This [sample](https://github.com/furmangg/automating-azure-analysis-services/blob/master/README.md#processazureas) includes an Until loop to wait until the processing succeeds.